# What are the objections raised by Radhagovinda Nath against the teachings of Srila Bhaktivinoda Thakura?

Tags: gaudiya-vaishnavism, chaitanya

Principal Radhagovinda Nath, D.Lit was one of the most renowned Gaudiya Vaishnava scholars respected throughout Bengal. He, in his famous book "Gaudiya Vaishnava Darshana" (1953), raised a series of objections based on scriptures and evidence that goes against the preachings of Srila Bhaktivinoda Thakura.

Sri Sundarananda Vidyavinoda was also a great Gaudiya scholar who wrote about the same in the 1940's.

I am interested to know the arguments of Sri Radhagovinda Nath. His works on the life and the teachings of Sri Chaitanydeva are phenomenal.One of his books is available online: https://archive.org/details/GauraTattva

Comment: Don't you have this book? And is it available online?

Comment: No, I dont have with me.And no, his writings --so beautiful--are mostly untranslated!

Comment: Can you scan it and put it online?

Comment: @Wikash_hindu First of all I dont have the book right now.Second, its in Bengali.So how many will understand even if somebody keeps it online?

Comment: Who is Radha Govinda Natha? @commonman

Comment: No I do not know about so many of them ..:) Thanks .. @commonman